# Use of ANTLR to multiple Parsing

Tags: java, xml, antlr, ttcn

**What I need** : Find a way to parse a ttcn-3 source code or a ttcn-3 schema into XML or JAVA

I have looked on the internet to see if I can find an IDE or a program that helps me to parse a code in a ttcn-3 language and I have found the ANTLR website. Another tool for language recognition so I would like to know if someone has used ANTLR or knows if it can help me to parse.

Comment: What they mean on the website is that when you have a question regarding an ANTLR grammar you are writing yourself, you can use stackoverflow.

Comment: Yes, you can use a parser generator (ANTLR is one of many) to implement a parser to TTCN-3 (or other languages).  Now you either have to find a grammar for such compatible with ANTLR, or build such a grammar yourself.  But it sounds like you don't understand enough about parser generators to easily benefit from this; suggest you take some time to get educated.  When you then have a specific problem with ANTLR or other parser generator, as Bart says, you can ask about that specific problem here.

Comment: On [SO] you need to have a specific problem, preferably with a specific piece of your own code. You ask for a tutorial – which is either too broad (we would need to write too much text), or asking for an external resource, which is off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely yes. I know many people who have used ANTLR (including myself) and it can be used to solve your problem and parse your language if you can find a grammar for it.

Comment: Ok thanks ut what does "grammar" means ? If the ttcn-3 grammar is in the ANTLRI can use it but if it is not included I have to build it ?

Comment: I don't get what is a "grammar" ? For example if I want to parser XML into JAVA, I have to find the grammar in the ANTLR to parse it ?

Comment: A grammar is a formal description of your language you want to parse (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammar). It describes how a machine processes certain input (that must conform to your language, here ttcn-3, or you will get a parse error). ANTLR will generate a parser based on your grammar that you can use to parse input. Writing a grammar is usually not trivial, so most people try to reuse existing grammars, if there are any. For XML you will certaily find a grammar, just google a bit.

Comment: Ok thanks but I need to parse from ttcn-3 to XML so I need to find a grammar for TTCN-3 right ? Or do I need to find a grammar for XML ?

Comment: If you want to parse ttcn-3 then you need a grammar that describes this language.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot, and I have just another question, I am trying to find tutorials to start with antlr and I have found two differents :
http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/04/antlr-tutorial-hello-word.html
https://github.com/alexnatch/antlr4ide

The two says tha t I need maven and Xtext, is it right ?

Tanks a lot again